# Printing pages from 7 to 17 by lpr

Tags: unix, lpr

**How can you print pages from 7 to 17 by lpr?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
lpr -P myprinter -o page-ranges=7-17
```

where `myprinter` is the name of your printer

Comment: How did you find the information about the flag: `- page-ranges=7-17
`.? It is not in my manual in Ubuntu.

Comment: I just Googled for "lpr page range" - and lo - first result

Comment: i think the command should be `-o page-ranges=7-17` not `- page-ranges=7-17`.  can't test since i have no printer, but you don't give your source so i can't look to see if the typo is yours or theirs.

Comment: @~quack That's correct. Not sure how I missed typing the missing letter.

Comment: Depending on how you installed lpr, -o may or may not work! See here: http://superuser.com/questions/230379/adobe-reader-seems-to-use-wrong-lpr-command-when-printing-to-cups and here: http://superuser.com/questions/371577/how-do-i-tell-aptitude-or-apt-to-offer-a-particular-version-of-lpr

Comment: @Masi Standard options are described [in CUPS online documentation](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html#OPTIONS).  And from the same page : "*Printer-specific options are also available and can be listed using the lpoptions command: `lpoptions -p printer -l`*".

Answer (score 3):

Masi, the command **IS** documented on your Ubuntu box, in the online-help for CUPS. Visit

http://localhost:631/help/options.html?TOPIC=Getting+Started&QUERY=#PAGERANGES

to see what I mean.

Comment: For some reason, the page-ranges options is not listed in the `man` page, though…

Answer (score 1):

`man lp` has the `-P` option for page range:

```
    -P page-list
        Specifies which pages to print in the document.  The list can contain a list of numbers and ranges  (#-#)  separated  by  commas,
        e.g.,  "1,3-5,16".   The  page numbers refer to the output pages and not the document's original pages - options like "number-up"
        can affect the numbering of the pages.
```

Here is a full command I use often:

`lp -P 5-22 -o media=A4 -o number-up=2 -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -o fit-to-page R-ints.pdf`