# Finding manuals for lpr

Tags: documentation, lpr

This thread is based on [the thread](https://superuser.com/questions/75553/printing-pages-from-7-to-17-by-lpr/75594#75594).

**Where are the newest manuals for lpr?**

I would like to know where the flags such as "page-range" are documented. I did not find them in Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/usr/bin/lpr` is either installed with the `cups-bsd` package or with the `lprng` package.  You can check which package you're using with `dpkg -S $(which lpr)`.

If you are using the CUPS package, some of the available options are listed in [`man lp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?lp) on your system.  You should also check [`http://localhost:631/help`](http://localhost:631/help) (yes, on *your* system) for CUPS built-in help.  The `page-ranges` option specifically is mentioned by [CUPS documentation](http://www.cups.org/doc-1.1/sum.html) (see [Document Options](http://www.cups.org/doc-1.1/sum.html#4_3), and [Command-Line Options](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html); these are also available in the online help page "Command-Line Printing and Options"):

> The `-o page-ranges=pages` option selects a range of pages for printing:
>
> ```
> lp -o page-ranges=1 filename
> lp -o page-ranges=1-4 filename
> lp -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename
> lpr -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename
> ```

If you're using LPRng, see the [LPRng project documentation](http://lprng.sourceforge.net/docs.html) page.  The [LPRng Reference Manual](http://lprng.sourceforge.net/LPRng-Reference-Multipart/index.htm) is still online, although the [Printing Cookbook](http://lprng.sourceforge.net/docs/PrintingCookbook) appears offline currently.  I don't see any specific references to a `page-ranges` option, but it's very possible the option was introduced in a very old LP or LPR implementation.

Comment: `http://localhost:631/help` gives me a blank page in Firefox. There are some available options available at `man lp` in my cups-bsd, but not `page-range`. Your given internet does have the given option. I cannot understand why Ubuntu is using Apple's manuals, since we have much better manuals provided by FSF.

Comment: Which is your Linux OS of choice? - I would like to have an OS distro which has explicit pieces of knowledge, not implicit like Ubuntu.

Comment: i use Debian, and Google to find any documentation i might be needing.  you won't find any distro of any OS that is perfectly documented.  for docs, you should be checking a) manpages, b) `info`, c) `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>`, d) the package homepage, e) Google.

Answer (score 3):

Uh...is

`man lpr`

not working for you? Are the man pages on your machine stored by a seperate package that you haven't installed yet?

---

I should clarify that there isn't **a** lpr. Rather there are many versions provided by many vendors (and notably by GNU), and not all versions support the same set of options. Have you tried the offending command and gotten it to work?

The Apple version is doubtless derived from one of the BSD versions, and probably supports a smaller set of options that the GNU version.

Comment: The command gives me the manual with the following notice at the bottom: "Copyright 2007 Apple Inc.". The manuals also do not apparently contain all information about lpr, since Sathya suggests that there is the option "-page-range" which is not documented in the manual. - I should perhaps use Arch Linux or Gentoo to get descent manuals.

Comment: `man lpr` on Ubuntu 9.04 doesn't include a listing of possible options, just details of how to specify those options.

Comment: Sometimes `info lpr` provides more detail, sometimes just refers to the man page.

Comment: @Masi: The man page is copyrighted by Apple because CUPS now is (since a few years ago) copyrighted by Apple. And CUPS ships with a complete set of man pages. These are the same on all Linux systems using CUPS (Debian-based systems in general often-times do extend poor and add missing man pages... I don't know if they did this for CUPS though.)

Comment: No, the Apple version isn't doubtless derived from one of the BSD versions! Apple (meanwhile) owns CUPS (but still keeps its GPL license). CUPS (http://www.cups.org/) isn't derived from **ANY** BSD version. CUPS is the implementation of a completely different printing system as compared to BSD printing. BSD printing is based on LPR/LPD. CUPS is based on IPP.

Answer (score 0):

Page range printing **IS** documented on every system that has a recent CUPS installed. Look here:

http://localhost:631/help/options.html?TOPIC=Getting+Started&QUERY=#PAGERANGES

(older systems also have it, the URL may be different however). That documentation normally should fit perfectly to your system.

If you indeed are looking for "the latest" documentation that is available for a released version of CUPS, look here:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php

If you look for "bleeding edge" documentation about (yet) unreleased versions of CUPS, look here:

http://svn.easysw.com/public/cups/trunk/doc/help/
http://svn.easysw.com/public/cups/trunk/man/
http://svn.easysw.com/public/cups/trunk/man/lpr.man
http://svn.easysw.com/public/cups/trunk/man/lp.man